# how to train GANs properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I started experimenting with gans and on the internet, there are a lot of options the thing I worry about now is which one should I use Keras fit or Keras train_on_batchs which one is the proper way to train the model thanks

Comment: I would go with `fit` because it wraps everything nicely. but you wont train it "better" with it just a bit different but probably the end result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

According to tensorflow's documentation, the combination of `tf.data` & `model.train_on_batch()` is the fastest way to train a model.
You can check more about `tf.data` in the link below:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data

I have already implemented GANs with keras. My implementations might help you get an idea how to train those models:
https://github.com/kochlisGit/Keras-GAN